# Exceeding maximum character limits when converting from .json to .csv

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, csv

I have some very large JSON files (from the Pushshift Reddit data dumps) I am extracting data from. I am using the following code to read the file into pandas in chunks, keep only cases from specific subreddits (specified in the list 'subs'), and then write the resulting dataframe to .csv.

```
with pd.read_json(filename+".json", lines=True, chunksize=100000) as reader:
        reader
        for chunk in reader: 
            df = pd.DataFrame(chunk)
            df.info()
            df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
            df = df.reindex(columns=df_titles)
            df['subreddit'] = df['subreddit'].str.lower()
            df = df[df['subreddit'].isin(subs)]                
            if os.path.exists("/data/"+year+"/"+filename+".csv"):
                df.to_csv("data"+year+"/"+filename+".csv", mode='a', header=False, index=False)
            else:
                df.to_csv("data"+year+"/"+filename+".csv", mode='w', header=True, index=False)
```

However, I run into issues with the resulting .csv file, because some of the intial JSON objects have text or nested objects that exceed the maximum character length for a .csv in Excel. As a result, the cell 'overflows' and everything after the character limit gets spread across the cells in the next row, like so: [image: JSON example]

It's even worse when it's post from texts, because the line breaks in the posts lead to even more issues once the data is loaded into Excel:
[image: text example]

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to fix the issue short of manually going through each .csv file, and my searches so far have been little help. Especially for the post texts, I don't want to truncate the text because they'll be a part of the analysis down the line. Is there a way to split these instances across multiple columns when the data is initially processed or, better yet, a way to read the existing files into pandas and fix the issue? (Processing the initial JSON files took a long time and I'd rather not repeat that if I don't have to.)

Comment: Surely Excel is the wrong way to look at data like this.  You're not going to do any analysis in Excel.  Why not just include the first 100 or 200 characters of the text?

Comment: Well, I really just want to import the .csv into Stata, but it runs into a similar issue so I assumed the problem was with the .csv formatting because even when I view it in a normal text editor, it tries to wrap the line?

Comment: A single cell in Excel is limited to 32,767 characters.  If you insist on Excel, you'll need to truncate it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For each string column you can do:

```
df_in = pd.DataFrame([["a" * i] for i in range(1, 8)], columns=["col"])

chunk_size = 3

def chunk_string(string, prefix):
    return {prefix + str(i): string[0 + i:chunk_size + i] for i in range(0, len(string), chunk_size)}

df_out = df_in["col"].map(lambda s: chunk_string(s, "col")).apply(pd.Series)
```

Result:

```
>>> df_in
       col
0        a
1       aa
2      aaa
3     aaaa
4    aaaaa
5   aaaaaa
6  aaaaaaa
>>> df_out
  col0 col3 col6
0    a  NaN  NaN
1   aa  NaN  NaN
2  aaa  NaN  NaN
3  aaa    a  NaN
4  aaa   aa  NaN
5  aaa  aaa  NaN
6  aaa  aaa    a
```

P.S. I would not recommend use Excel for this purpose. You will struggle a lot with data like this

Comment: I plan to do the actual analysis in Stata, but right now the .csv reads in with similar issues? I assumed the problem was with the .csv formatting because even when I view it in a normal text editor, it wraps the line? Unless there is something I'm missing.

Comment: Well, probably your strings has some special characters (like "\n" - line break).  You can try to replace occurrences of them to, for example, space. Or any other character(s) to indicate line break for analysis purposes.

Comment: Thank you for this; I've been able to split my long strings. Do you know how I might add those columns to the existing dataframe (or, keep them linked to another column in the original dataframe so that I can append them afterwards)?

Comment: pd.merge on index column